# Controller private method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an app where users can post. Each post an be upvoted and downvoted. Where the posts are displayed, I have a little  form that allows the user to filter the posts. It simply passes a paramter to url called params[:post_filter] (localhost:3000/somepage?post_filter=value). Now, this works just fine and dandy, except the private method I wrote to modify the query does not work.

Here is my query:

```
def room
            @posts = Post.where('lesson_id = ?', params[:id]).order(post_filter_params).page(params[:page]).per(30)
    end
```

and here is my private method:

```
private

def post_filter_params
    chosen_option = params[:post_filter].to_i == 1 or 2 or 3 ? params[:post_filter] : '1'
    case chosen_option
    when 1
        'created_at DESC'
    when 2
        'upvotes DESC'
    when 3
        'downvotes DESC'
    end
end
```

Now, whenever I replace the .order() value with one of the strings in my private method, everything works as planned. However, placing private method name inside the .order() value does not work. Any ideas for what is going on?

**EDIT**

To make sure all values are the same data type I did this but it still does not work:

```
def post_filter_params
    param_option = params[:post_filter].to_i
    chosen_option = param_option == 1 or 2 or 3 ? param_option : 1
    case chosen_option
    when 1
        'created_at DESC'
    when 2
        '(upvotes - downvotes) DESC'
    when 3
        'downvotes DESC'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that private method does what you think it does.

How about this?

```
def post_filter_params
  case params[:post_filter].to_i
  when 1
    'created_at DESC'
  when 2
    'upvotes DESC'
  when 3
    'downvotes DESC'
  else
    'created_at DESC'
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, your code works, but the private is not an issue. I thank you good sir. http://i.imgur.com/cHapI.jpg

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't what I meant. I was referring to the `chosen_option = param_option == 1 or 2 or 3 ? param_option : 1` line.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare numbers with numbers or strings with strings.

Quote 1, 2, and 3

```
when '1'
...
```

Or convert `chosen_options` to number

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain the point of @shioyama. First, let's focus on this code:

```
param_option = params[:post_filter].to_i
chosen_option = param_option == 1 or 2 or 3 ? param_option : 1
```

In an IRB session..

```
irb(main):005:0> param_option = 1
=> 1
irb(main):006:0> chosen_option = param_option == 1 or 2 or 3 ? param_option : 1
=> true
irb(main):007:0> chosen_option
=> true
irb(main):008:0> param_option = 2
=> 2
irb(main):009:0> chosen_option = param_option == 1 or 2 or 3 ? param_option : 1
=> 2
irb(main):010:0> chosen_option
=> false
```

So, the line `chosen_option = param_option == 1 or 2 or 3 ? param_option : 1` is the same as `chosen_option = (param_option == 1) or (2) or (3 ? param_option : 1)`, that will be either `true` or `false`.

What you wanted is, probably: `chosen_option = param_option == 1 || param_option == 2 || param_option == 3 ? param_option : 1`.

```
irb(main):036:0> chosen_option = param_option == 1 || param_option == 2 || param_option == 3 ? param_option : 1
=> 3
irb(main):037:0> chosen_option
=> 3
```

A common shortcut for that is `chosen_option = [1, 2, 3].include?(param_option) ? param_option : 1`. But in this case, the best would be what @shioyama suggested:

```
def post_filter_params
  case params[:post_filter].to_i
  when 2
    'upvotes DESC'
  when 3
    'downvotes DESC'
  # you can just fallback to else
  # when 1
  #   'created_at DESC'
  else
    'created_at DESC'
  end
end
```

And a last tip: consider using `CONSTANTS` instead of magic numbers, it will help others reading your code and yourself in a (non long) future :)